# Example of sum of log-concave is not always log-concave

Tags: convex-analysis

I know that sum of log-concave is not always log-concave.

Could anyone provides me with an example to prove this?

Like probability distribution fn (pdf) of normal distribution is log-concave;
on what condition, the sum of two pdf will not be log-concave?

Thanks!!

:)

Comment: You remarked that the Gaussian functions associated with normal distributions are log-concave. Have you tried experimenting with adding two Gaussian functions together, to see if you can create an example where the sum is not log-concave? I particularly like the idea of having the two Gaussians be centered at different points....

Comment: Given that log-concavity is preserved under convolution, you will have to look only at sums of dependent random variables. There are various way to capture dependency - for example, try a copula approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example. Consider the density of two exponential random variables as
\begin{align*}
f_1(x) &=\lambda_1 \exp(-\lambda_1x) \\
f_2(x) &=\lambda_2 \exp(-\lambda_2x),
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.

Consider the sum of these two log concave functions
\begin{align*}
g(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x),
\end{align*}
where the first and second derivatives of $g(x)$ are given as: 
\begin{align*}
g^{'}(x) &=- \lambda_1 ^2 \exp(-\lambda_1x) - \lambda_2^2 \exp(-\lambda_2x) \\
g^{''}(x) &= \lambda_1 ^3 \exp(-\lambda_1x) + \lambda_2^3 \exp(-\lambda_2x)
\end{align*}

One can show that $g^{'}(x)g^{'}(x)\le g^{''}(x)g(x)$, hence $g(x)$ is not log-concave. In fact, it is log-convex.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit on this "on can show"? It's clearly not true for ALL $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ (take one equal to zero...), so does one actually show it?

Comment: (i.e., it only holds as long as the two parameters are both non zero, besides being distinct)